# Regarding refs in react JS / Can I use a ref to set component's state?

Tags: reactjs, ref, react-ref

In the code below I'm unable to use this.setState({name: this.nameRef.current.value}). Can someone please tell why is this happening? Once I've something in ref's current value, why can't I use it to update the component's current state? Also, Is it a wrong practise? However it doesn't matter If it doesn't work.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    console.log('constructor');
    super();
    this.state = {name : '', password: ''}
    this.nameRef = React.createRef()
    this.pwdRef = React.createRef()
  }

  handleLogin = (val) =>{
      val.preventDefault();
      this.setState({name: this.nameRef.current.value}) //Not working
      alert("Welcome"+this.nameRef.current.value);
      console.log(this.state.name); //Outputs empty string
  }
    render(){
      return(
        <React.Fragment>
          <form>
            <div className={"form-group"}>
              <label>Username: </label>
              <input style={{width: '60%', display: 'inline'}} name="name" type="text" className={"form-control"} placeholder="Enter name" ref={this.nameRef}/>
            </div>
            <div className={"form-group"}>
              <label>Password: </label>
              <input style={{width: '60%', display: 'inline'}} type="text" name="pass" className={"form-control"} placeholder="Enter password" ref={this.pwdRef}/>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className={"btn btn-primary"} onClick={this.handleLogin}> Login </button>
          </form>
        </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it a bad practice? Yes. Why don't you use value and onChange props?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know why can't I set the state when I click Submit but onChange() solved my issue. This works just fine :

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    console.log('constructor');
    super();
    this.state={name: '',password: ''}
    this.nameRef = React.createRef()
    this.pwdRef = React.createRef()
  }

  setStat1 = () =>{
    this.setState({name: this.nameRef.current.value})
  }

  setStat2 = () =>{
    this.setState({password: this.pwdRef.current.value})
  }

  handleLogin = (val) =>{
    console.log(this.state.name+" : "+this.state.password)
      val.preventDefault();
      alert("Welcome"+this.nameRef.current.value);
  }
    render(){
      return(
        <React.Fragment>
          <form>
            <div className={"form-group"}>
              <label>Username: </label>
              <input style={{width: '60%', display: 'inline'}} name="name" type="text" className={"form-control"} onChange={this.setStat1} placeholder="Enter name" ref={this.nameRef}/>
            </div>
            <div className={"form-group"}>
              <label>Password: </label>
              <input style={{width: '60%', display: 'inline'}} type="text" name="pass" className={"form-control"} placeholder="Enter password" onChange={this.setStat2} ref={this.pwdRef}/>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className={"btn btn-primary"} onClick={this.handleLogin}> Login </button>
          </form>
        </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not a good solution. Imagine you have to add more inputs. You would need to define more methods to change the state. What you want to do is define one method and use the event or value that gets passed to set the state. And for the onChange, send the id of the field so you know which input changed (in user's input, you send 'user', etc.)

Comment: It's good practice for this site to select the correct answer instead of posting your own, just FYI.

Comment: I know but what I wanted really was how I can use state to set a current ref value. I know this code won't come in handy If you were to build something complex and obviously I won't go with this approach either. It was just something out of curiosity. And because this was something I was hoping to do, I found a way to do it. That's why posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best practice.  Add an `onChange` prop to your inputs, like:

```
onChangeName = e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value });

...

<input ...other things... onChange={this.onChangeName} value={this.state.name} />
```

This way, whenever a user types into an input, that automatically updates the state.  Refs should be used sparingly, as React usually has better ways to accomplish most things.

Answer (score 1):

Before answering your question, what you should be doing is tracking each input's value to the corresponding state variable. You can do this with the onChange listener (you get the value via the event.target.value)

However, to address the question, what you are asking is if you can use refs to get the value from a component and use it. You can, and you should be seeing the value, what I think it's happening is that the input isn't updating 'value' (which you will when you control it with onChange and value={this.state.variableName}). After implementing the onChange and stuff try to log the input value using ref, see if it changes